# If inside Where mysql

Tags: mysql

Can I do an if inside Where? 
or something that allows me to do the checks only if the field is not null (path=null)

```
SELECT  
IF(path IS NOT NULL, concat("/uploads/attachments/",path, "/thumbnails/" , nome), "/uploads/attachments/default/thumbnails/avatar.png") as avatar_mittente
FROM prof_foto  
WHERE profilo_id = 15 
 -- only if path != "/uploads/attachments/default/thumbnails/avatar.png"
AND foto_eliminata = 0 AND foto_profilo = 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this

```
SELECT  
IF(path IS NOT NULL, concat("/uploads/attachments/",path, "/thumbnails/" , nome), "/uploads/attachments/default/thumbnails/avatar.png") as avatar_mittente
FROM prof_foto  
WHERE profilo_id = 15 
AND IF( path != "/uploads/attachments/default/thumbnails/avatar.png", 
         foto_eliminata = 0 AND foto_profilo = 1,
        foto_eliminata like '%' AND foto_profilo like '%'
        )
```

Comment: Welcome. I am happy for that!

Answer (score 0):

You can just use binary logic for this:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE A
(if b then also where C)
```

Becomes

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE A 
AND (!b OR C)
```

In your case:

```
SELECT  
IF(path IS NOT NULL, concat("/uploads/attachments/",path, "/thumbnails/" , nome), "/uploads/attachments/default/thumbnails/avatar.png") as avatar_mittente
FROM prof_foto  
WHERE profilo_id = 15 
AND (path = "/uploads/attachments/default/thumbnails/avatar.png" OR foto_eliminata = 0 AND foto_profilo = 1))
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use `IF()` wherever a value is expected, even though most of the time it is not the best route to take.

```
WHERE IF(path IS NULL, portfolio_id = 15, TRUE)
```

But prefer:

```
WHERE path IS NULL OR portfolio_id = 15
```

(notice you cannot compare with `NULL`, `[anything] = NULL` is always `FALSE`)